# Does ignite support nested schemas?

Tags: apache-spark, ignite

When using spark, Dataframe can have nested schemas, and this can be saved in parquet format.

I am considering using [ignite](https://ignite.apache.org/whatisignite.html) improve performance of my spark jobs, and they are using nested schemas (for storing [complex objects](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/dataframes-datasets/complex-nested-data.html))

Is it supported by ignite ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yves.

Currently, Ignite doesn't support reading or writing nested schemas.
You can file a ticket in Ignite Jira - https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/IGNITE/ and I will try to implement this feature.